What is the GitHub eqivolent of GitLab's CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE?
GitLab provides a lot "predefined-variables" which contain useful stuff prepopulated to help you write rules. Two examples of that are

CI_COMMIT_DESCRIPTION The description of the commit. If the title is shorter than 100 characters, the message without the first line.
CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE The full commit message.


One method to test the contents of the git commit message is a mix of contains and github.event.head_commit.message
contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '#BUILD')

Also reported that github.event.head_commit.message is only available on push events
